# can I see the checkins on project like weka

Tags: open-source, weka

I want to know the process of updates that occurred to open source project like weka https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/ so How can I see the checkins by date, and how can I contribute to already exist package of weka ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use SVN: https://www.google.com/search?q=svn+introduction

If you have mac or linux then you should be able to just checkout the repo from a terminal like:

```
dethstaw:src gardner$ svn co https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk weka
```

To start contributing to an open source project the easiest thing to do is to look for the bug tracker and start fixing known issues. (they love that) I found the bug tracker using Google https://www.google.com/search?q=weka+bug+tracker

Good luck in your new adventure.